# Why doesn't "history | vim" work?

Tags: linux, bash, vim

I want to use the Vim to see the result of `history` (not in the shell). I think `history | vim` will work (use the result of `history` as the input of `vim`), but it returns with:

```
$history | vim
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...

Vim: Finished.
```

Can anybody explain this?

Comment: If you want to use vim as a pager [vimpager](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager) seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By piping into **vim**, you are changing the standard input stream.  Because **vim** is an interactive program, it requires the standard input to be the console.

If you want to view in vim, you should tell it you are reading the file from stdin (by supplying the argument `-`):

```
history | vim -
```

Alternatively, you could just use **more** or **less**:

```
history | more
history | less
```

These latter two are preferable.  If you pipe into **vim**, it will see your "file" as having modifications, and so you can't quit with a straight `:q` command.  Instead you have to force quit by `:q!`, which is a bit clunky.

On the other hand, you can exit **more** or **less** just by typing `q`.  Have a look at the man-page for these two programs.  You'll use them a lot.

---

As recommended by Russell Silva in the comments, you can open **vim** in read-only mode when you read from stdin.  Just supply the `-R` argument.  Then you can quit normally without needing the override:

```
history | vim -R -
```

Comment: I have tried `vim | history` also... It seems something horrible happened.. The result is the shell is not responsable.. I can't input any instructions.. Could you please explain this to me?

Comment: Oh dear.  What you did was tie the output of `vim` to the input of `history`.  That's not a good idea.  Remember, `vim` is still running because it's an interactive program.  You can still send it commands because it is still reading from standard input, but you can't see it because you are piping its output into another program.  If you type `:q!` and press enter, you should return to the shell.  You might have to press the `Esc` key a few times if you've gotten into some other editing mode.

Comment: Wow...when I type `:q!` and press enter, I return to shell... It works.. Really thanks~

Comment: No problem.  Be careful.  Linux is very powerful, and sometimes you can do a lot of damage by experimenting.

Comment: Counld you please give me more information about `changing the standard input stream` and `it requires the standard input to be the console`? What is a console? Is it terminal? If history returns `a.txt`(I know it's impossible but I just assume it), `history | vim` will make vim open the `a.txt`(assume `a.txt` exists) ?

Comment: Have a read up about [Standard Streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) on Wikipedia and maybe have a look at this introduction to [Streams, Pipes and Redirects](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-lpic1-v3-103-4/) from IBM.

Comment: @paddy You can solve the `:q` problem by using readonly mode, e.g., `history | vim -R -`. Try it out! Perhaps consider editing your answer.

Comment: @RussellSilva: `view` is typically equivalent to `vim -R`, and easier to remember and type.

Answer (score 1):

Apart of `vim -`, you may try bash command substitution like:

```
vim <(history)
```

See also:

- [How to write whole buffer to standard output from the command line?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/798/how-to-write-whole-buffer-to-standard-output-from-the-command-line) at Vim SE
- [How to edit files non-interactively (e.g. in pipeline)?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/788/how-to-edit-files-non-interactively-e-g-in-pipeline) at Vim SE

Comment: +1. I like this solution (also successfully tested on Ubuntu, since the "`vi`" there is in fact a symlink to `/usr/bin/vim.tiny`). Escapes me why you got a downvote for it, though. People can be cruel at times. :)

Answer (score -1):

This happend to me trying to send it to background console (&)

One script used:

```
... 
vi "$file" &
...
# change to just:

vi "$file"
```

removing &, problem went away.

Comment: This is in no way related to the question…