# Why does vim crash when it becomes an orphan process?

Tags: c, linux, vim, fork, exec

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    int pid = fork();
    
    if (pid) {
        sleep(5);
        // wait(NULL); // works fine when waited for it.
    } else {
        execlp("vim", "vim", (char *)NULL);
    }
}
```

When I run this code, vim runs normally then crashes after the 5 seconds (i.e. when its parent exits). When I wait for it (i.e. not letting it become an orphan process), the code works totally fine.

Why does becoming an orphan process become a problem here? Is it something specific to vim?

Why is this even a thing that's visible to vim? I thought that only the parent knows when its children die. But here, I see that somehow, the child notices when it gets adopted, something happens and crashes somehow. Do the children processes get notified when their parent dies as well?

When I run this code, I get this output after the crash:

```
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: preserving files...
Vim: Finished.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't "history | vim" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713421/why-doesnt-history-vim-work)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+Error+reading+input%2C+exiting

Comment: @phd No actually. If you think this answers it somehow, I'd be thankful if you write an answer to this question.

Comment: In what way "**vim** is an interactive program, it requires the standard input to be the console" is not an answer?

Comment: Excellent question! I hope my answer is clear enough. At least, there are some practical experiments you can do to see things by yourself too. Unfortunately, the topic of foreground process groups and controlling terminals is quite complex (one of the most complex parts of Unix/Linux), so it's hard to cover it in depth here... But at least I hope my answer will give you enough pointers if you want to find out more about it yourself! Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually happens because of the *shell* that is executing the binary that forks Vim!

When the shell runs a foreground command, it creates a new process group and makes it the foreground process group of the terminal attached to the shell. In bash 5.0, you can find the code that transfers this responsibility in [`give_terminal_to()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/jobs.c?h=bash-5.0#n4456), which uses [`tcsetpgrp()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsetpgrp) to set the foreground process group.

It is necessary to set the foreground process group of a terminal correctly, so that the program running in foreground can get signals from the terminal (for example, Ctrl+C sending an interrupt signal, Ctrl+Z sending a terminal stop signal to suspend the process) and also change terminal settings in ways that full-screen programs such as Vim typically do. (The subject of foreground process group is a bit out of scope for this question, just mentioning it here since it plays part in the response.)

When the process (more precisely, the pipeline) executed by the shell terminates, the shell will take back the foreground process group, using the same `give_terminal_to()` code by calling it with the *shell*'s process group.

This is usually fine, because at the time the executed pipeline is finished, there's usually no process left on that process group, or if there are any, they typically don't hold on to the terminal (for example, if you're launching a background daemon from the shell, the daemon will typically close the stdin/stdout/stderr streams to relinquish access to the terminal.)

But that's not really the case with the setup you proposed, where Vim is still attached to the terminal and part of the foreground process group. When the parent process exits, the shell assumes the pipeline is finished and it will set the foreground process group back to itself, "stealing" it from the former foreground process group which is where Vim is. Consequently, the next time Vim tries to read from the terminal, the read will fail and Vim will exit with the message you reported.

One way to see by yourself that the parent processing exiting does *not* affect Vim by itself is running it through `strace`. For example, with the following command (assuming `./vim-launcher` is your binary):

```
$ strace -f -o /tmp/vim-launcher.strace ./vim-launcher
```

Since `strace` is running with the `-f` option to follow forks, it will also start tracing Vim when it's launched. The shell will be executing `strace` (not `vim-launcher`), so its foreground pipeline will only end when `strace` stops running. And `strace` will not stop running until Vim exits. Vim will work just fine past the 5 seconds, even though it's been reparented to init.

There also used to be an [`fghack` tool](https://github.com/daemontools/daemontools/blob/1e71548fe842c45cc3152caa0d22d9bc09b5527e/src/fghack.c), part of daemontools, that accomplished the same task of blocking until all forked children would exit. It would accomplish that by creating a new pipe and have the pipe inherited by the process it spawned, in a way that would get automatically inherited by all other forked children. That way, it could block until all copies of that pipe file descriptor were closed, which typically only happens when all processes exit (unless a background process goes out of its way to close all inherited file descriptors, but that's essentially stating that they don't want to be tracked, and they would most probably have relinquished their access to the terminal by that point.)